# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un formulario html a un Correo con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, html-correo

**Hice un formulario de preinscripcion con JavaScript**, css y HTML, y quisiera saber si puedo enviar a un correo con JavaScript, ya he intentado usar PHP, y en el servidor local me funciona, pero en subo a un servidor y me restringe y no envia y no se que pasa.

Mi codigo de PHP

```
<?php
//Llamando a los campos
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
$cursos = $_POST["Cursos"];
$java = $_POST["java"];
$android = $_POST["android"];
$ionic=$_POST["ionic"];
$sql = $_POST["sql"];
$apirestful = $_POST["apirestful"];
$ios = $_POST["ios"];
$seleccion = $_POST["seleccion"];

//Condicion de checkbox

if(isset($_POST["android"])) {
        echo $_POST["android"]; // Imprimes o haces tu lógica ;)
    }

    if(isset($_POST["java"])) {
        echo $_POST["java"];
    }

    if(isset($_POST["ionic"])) {
        echo $_POST["ionic"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["sql"])) {
        echo $_POST["sql"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["apirestful"])) {
      echo $_POST["apirestful"];
     }
     if(isset($_POST["ios"])) {
       echo $_POST["ios"];
      }
//Datos para el Correo

$destinatario = "juansepor00@gmail.com";
$asunto = "Pre Inscripcion de Curso Cygnus";

$carta = "De: $name \n";
$carta .= "Correo: $email \n ";
$carta .= "Telefono: $telefono \n";
$carta .= "Empresa: $empresa \n";
$carta .= "Como se entero del curso: $seleccion \n";
$carta .= "Cursos: $java \n";
$carta .= "$android \n";
$carta .= "$sql \n";
$carta .= "$apirestful \n";
$carta .= "$ios \n";
$carta .= "$ionic \n";

//EnViando Mensaje

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);

header('location:mensajeEnvio.html');


 ?>
```

Comment: Hola Juanse. Pones tu codigo de PHP, pero qué problemas concretos tuviste? Explicalo mejor siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Respecto a tu pregunta de JS, el trabajo de investigacion corre por tu parte y en la pregunta has de plantear lo invetigado, probado y los problemas especificos. Un saludo

Comment: Fijate en los logs del servidor que error te está tirando y adjuntalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Pues yo te diría que usaras la clase phpmailer de php para mandar correos. Es fácil de usar, es potente y te permite mandar correos en html y personalizarle bastante el aspecto al email con CSS incluso. Aquí sacarás más info sobre phpmailer--->https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer